# Please get me outta here.. Stubborn APIPA

Tags: networking, network-adapter, ip-address, tcpip

Any one please help me.. I am getting an APIPA since three days.. I did all the steps mentioned in [answers to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/324551/stubborn-apipa-issue-possible-ipv4-problem-ipv6-okay). Still they did not resolve my problem. At last I formatted whole of my computer and installed windows 7 all over again. Now my computer has only windows 7 (I mean no anti-virus, no firewall, not even a single software) and my IP is still169.x.x.x (APIPA). Please help me regarding this issue. I even changed the ends of my Ethernet cable. Is my NIC has gone bad and should I replace it?

Comment: "I did all the steps mentioned above" - what steps?

Comment: What is the Ethernet cable connected to? Do other machines connected to that same device work? Is the port light on for the port connected to that computer?

Comment: Probably refers to http://superuser.com/questions/324551/stubborn-apipa-issue-possible-ipv4-problem-ipv6-okay where he's posted the same thing as an answer

Comment: -Ipconfig release/renew
-Uninstalling/reinstalling the NIC driver
-Checking device manager for "hidden" NIC drivers (none)
-Flushing DNS and ARP
-Resetting winsock and ipv4 using netsh
-Manually assigning an IP address on my subnet
-Doing a system restore to before the Windows update
-Restarting DHCP client service
-Disabling Windows Firewall
-Unloading TrendMicro
-Malware Bytes scan

Comment: these were the steps which I performed earlier.. @Journey Geek : YEs I wrongly posted it as an answer to the other post.. But This ks the problem which I am facing. The Ethernet Cable is connected from one end  (port no.1) in the router to back of my desktop. But I cannot see any light at the back of the CPU where I connect the cable. But when I uninstall my NIC from device manager, on restarting, windows automatically detects my NIC and installs it. What should be my next step?

Comment: Have you tried to change the cable?

Comment: Yup I changed my ethernet cable with a new one... But still the same issue.. I dont understand my compputer was working perfectly fine before. But now I have re-installed windows and there is nothing except just windows, still the problem persists.

Comment: Does anyone has a real solution for the problem mentioned above?